NodeTree Pointer Property Not Saving in Scene Property Group
I'm developing a Blender addon and have encountered an issue with saving and restoring a NodeTree pointer property within a custom PropertyGroup registered to the scene.
I have defined the PropertyGroup and the PointerProperty like this:
import bpy
from bpy.utils import register_class

class MYADDON_AddonProps(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    node_tree_id: bpy.props.PointerProperty(
        type=bpy.types.NodeTree
    )
    
register_class(MYADDON_AddonProps)

bpy.types.Scene.my_addon_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(
    type=MYADDON_AddonProps
)

When I assign a node tree to this property, it works fine while the file is open. I can save and restore its value without any issues:
bpy.context.scene.my_addon_props.node_tree_id = bpy.data.materials[1].node_tree

However, after saving the file and reopening it, the node_tree_id value is empty.
Interestingly, the same approach works perfectly when using bpy.types.Material instead of a NodeTree, the stored material persists after saving and reopening the file.
What I've Tried:

Assigning the node tree to the PointerProperty and checking its value before saving the file.
Ensuring that the node tree exists and is properly referenced.

Observations:

The property works as expected during the session.
The property value does not persist after saving and reopening the file.

Question:
Why does the node_tree_id pointer property not persist after saving and reopening the Blender file? Is there a specific step I am missing or a known limitation with NodeTree pointer properties in custom property groups?
Additional Information:

Blender Version: 4.1.0 (also tried 3.5)
OS: Windows


Is it not possible to save the material?
I think you can use "bpy.types.Material" and learn the node tree afterwards.
NodeTree".
In the,,.
Geomery node seems to work fine.

I'm able to confirm this behavior. Even tried with specific subclass bpy.data.ShaderNodeTree to no avail. Why not just use the bpy.types.Material then as suggested by mml? Then you can just access material.node_tree which is the same value you try to access/save.

@mml Thank you for your suggestion! However, I'm creating an operator that gets this id_data directly from the context menu. From the context menu, I'm only receiving the bpy.types.NodeTree type, and I haven't found a way to get the Material id_data from this NodeTree type. Is there any way to retrieve the Material from a NodeTree?

next(m for m in bpy.data.materials if m.node_tree == node_tree) ?

You should save NodeTree pointer property in Material custom property as type=bpy.types.ShaderNodeTree
import bpy

class MYADDON_AddonProps(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    node_tree_id: bpy.props.PointerProperty(
        type=bpy.types.ShaderNodeTree
    )

bpy.types.Material.my_addon_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(
    type=MYADDON_AddonProps
)


Thank you for your answer! Where do we save it? Instead using bpy.context.scene.my_addon_props.node_tree_id what do we use?

bpy.data.marerials["Material"].my_addon_props.node_tree_id would be the path on a given material. There are other ways to get to a specific materials though.

@Gorgious hmmm i find it weird that we save it on the material when the material itself already has the node tree in bpy.data.marerials["Material"].node_tree XD

Thank you for your answer! But is this indeed the only expected way to save a NodeTree using PointerProperties? Or is it some kind of bug and this option is an alternative? This method allows me to save the NodeTree, but I still need access to the Material reference, which is not my case. So I would need an approach similar to what was suggested by @Gorgious above.

AFAIK a shader node tree cannot exist in a vacuum, it needs to be tied to a material so it might explain the discrepancy

@Gorgious That makes sense!
